# Strange behavior for navLinks: In week-view, cklicking on a date, the month-view will be rendered

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

When I select the month-view (or the year-view), and I click on the date of a day, the day-view is rendered -> ok.
However, when the week-view is selected, the same procedure renders the month view. For me this is strange.

Look at https://codepen.io/hrigu/pen/bJxzaG?editors=0010 for a demonstration.

I tried to define a navLinkMonthClick, since this is called in the week-view when clicking on a day

```
 navLinkMonthClick: function(date, jsEvent) {
    console.log('month-click');
    //render the day-view here...
}
```

Now I want to initialize the day-view and render the selected day.
How can I do that?

Comment: If you think you've found a bug in the fullCalendar code then please [report it](https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs) . We can't help you with that here.